# Rewrite domain to contain path prefix

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Having some trouble with this rewrite code. I want to add a few domains (all pointing to the same server) and make it so that they have a "hidden" URL prefix being sent to the server.

Example: You type in `example-one.org/contact`, the server looks at it as `/one/contact/`

### Updated code based on @anubhava's answer

I still receive a 500 Internal Server Error when using this code. I put it through an [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it looks like it should work.

Here is the full htaccess code, including WordPress' defaults, and without using example.org:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^discoverdowntownspringfield.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!downtown-springfield/).*)$ /downtown-springfield/$1 [L,NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!one/).*)$ /one/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I like the regex instead of using a REQUEST_URI condition. But I still receive a 500 error. I have updated my answer with the full .htaccess, including wordpress' code. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Oh damn wordpress. Had you told me before about presence of WP I wouldn't have posted answer. WP is pretty rigid about its own front controller and doesn't like other internal rewrites. Putting a `R` will make URL change but if `/downtown-springfield/abcd` is WP URI then you will get 404 I suspect.

Comment: I assumed that if WordPress came second, my code would have a chance to fix things. But I cannot even get it to reach wordpress's index.php, which has a var_dump and exit statement at the top.

Comment: Actually it would still not cause 500 even if WP will be a spoilsport later. Can you check Apache error.log to see why 500 is showing up.